# using facebook oAuth permissions to auto register user on a wordpress powered site

Tags: facebook, wordpress, oauth

I maybe totally barking up the wrong tree here but I just cant seem to find anything thats helping me on this subject.

Here's the deal, I have created a wordpress site that is set up as a classifieds 'free ads' site.
I dont intend for it to be used as a website, only as an app within facebook.

I have set up my application on FB, looked at various different types of wordpress plugins etc but cant find what I'm looking for.

When a user adds my app on facebook they get presented with the permissions dialog 'allow this app to blah blah blah etc' when accepting this they then see teh wordpress site in the iFrame, but i then have to run another plugin to enable facebook registration/login. which in turn will of course then bring up another authorisation dialogue.

Is there a way of just using the initial permissions dialogue to pass credentials to my Wordpress site so that it automatically creates a registration enabling the user to get straight in and use the app?

sorry if i havent been technical enough, and also, if there is someone out there that knows this like the back of their hand, i'd be interested in paying for someone to do this?

thanks
Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to bypass Facebook's oAuth permissions, you're not going to be able to.  If you're looking for a tutorial of some sort on how to create a Facebook login for your website then I'd suggest [the following article from the Facebook Developer's site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login).

If you'd rather not mess with such code, then you can always implement the social plugins made by Facebook themselves.  They have a [login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/) and a [registration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) plugin which allows you to add these features to your website a lot easier than coding through the previous article.  My experience is that the official documentation for Facebook's API is your best resource and there's not a ton of tutorials out there which are better than just reading the documentation.  If you're new to back-end programming (entirely a naive assumption) then I would highly suggest reading the docs, otherwise it's going to be pretty hard to implement what I believe you're trying to do.

Comment: Hey many thanks for taking the time to reply.
Your assumptions are somewhat correct, I dont really code much past implementing basic stuff that I can patch together etc. I more of a designer.
So what you are saying is it involves changing wordpress's existing codebase for registering new users?
if thats the way to go then fine, but where might I find a person willing to carry out such a task as I'm not capable of going that far


The plugins that I have found that are available add in an extra step which I find undesirable the user ends up having to click on two auth dialogs which I dont like.

Comment: If you're starting fresh on a website and you don't have anybody but yourself and people who edit the website needing to have an account, then don't allow people to sign up through Wordpress.  I'd use one or the other, not try to get one to implement with the other.  Save yourself the time and effort.